# Can chiseled stone brick be used to craft stone tool items like furnaces and brewing stands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is a pretty specific question, but it's in relation to a challenge where you don't start with a lava bucket in Skyblock. Without starting lava, I'm trying to figure out if there are any other ways of crafting stone items.

One possibility I've come across is trading with a Mason villager who sometimes sells 4 Chiseled Stone Bricks for 1 Emerald.

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Comment: I don't have Minecraft yet in my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ben's answer is not up-to-date.

Since the release of 1.16 chiseled stone bricks are needed (together with a netherite ingot) to craft a [Lodestone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lodestone):

[image: screenshot of Lodestone crafting recipe]

As of 1.19, there is no other recipe where they can be used, as it can be seen [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone_Bricks#Usage).

Answer (score 0):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Chiseled_Stone_Bricks#Trivia):

> Chiseled stone bricks are currently only used as decoration.

To obtain a chiseled stone brick block through crafting, you need to obtain 4 stone, craft them into stone bricks, cut that into stone brick slabs, then remerge them. This is a one-way process, and the only form of stone usable in crafting tools and furnaces etc., is cobblestone.

Comment: I know that's not correct because blackstone and cobbled deepslate can be used to craft furnaces.

Comment: Correct, because they are the same form of material. I.e. on the same level as cobblestone. They can also be smelted and crafted into other things, and once they are, they are no longer usable as a crafting material.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. So stone doesn't work for making furnaces, but cobblestone does. And a crafted item like chiseled stone brick which has already been modified is no longer the "cobble" type?